# Chess set icons

Tags: chessboards, pieces

I am looking for an examples of a free chess set icons. It would be nice if the place allow to download them, but this is not really important, as I will still need to redraw them in svg format.

Just to explain what I mean by chess set icons. I need them to customize user's pieces on my chess server. Basically I am looking for examples like this (image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chess_symbols.PNG)):

[image]

but not like this (image from [TheChessPiece](http://www.thechesspiece.com/proddetail.asp?prod=Jazzy-Trio-Knight)): 
[image]

Also is it possible that some particular chess icons are patented and hence I can not use them?

Comment: I'd recommend the chess symbols in "DejaVu Serif", a free font.  I think they're quite good-looking.

Comment: Icons aren't patentable, but some might be copyrighted.

Comment: @lily According to [this page](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/dejavu_serif_condensed/blockview.htm?block=miscellaneous_symbols), the chess pieces ([unicodes U+2654 to U+265F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode#The_basic_12_chess_pieces)) seem to be missing for DejaVu Serif? They exist for DejaVu Sans, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might look for a chess set *font*. [Here are several](http://www.enpassant.dk/chess/fonteng.htm). Licensing information is included. It looks like they have been scanned from old books in some cases.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was searching for. The quality is bad, but this gives me an example how should I draw them. Thanks for a swift reply.

Comment: and actually I am wrong. Only previews do not look nice, inside the zip folder there are fonts, which have nice quality.

Comment: A closer look at the page will tell you that the majority of the fonts mentioned have "designers". None were scanned. Please pay attention and respect the work freely given to the chess community.

Comment: When using a font, though, I guess the white part of the interior of the pieces are not going to become white, but instead transparent?

Answer (score 23):

[PyChess](http://pychess.org/) has about 20 fonts and SVGs bundled [in its source code](https://github.com/pychess/pychess/tree/master/pieces):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The cat one appeals to the old cat lady in me.

Comment: @PaulElfish Though it would be rather humiliating to be checkmated by a litter-tray...

Comment: The fact that this project is licences under GPL v.3 means that any other project that uses anything from this project (including images) also has to be licensed under GPL v.3 and thus also be open source, doesn’t it?

Answer (score 13):

Unicode has chess piece icons in it.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode

This means you could look for a font which includes the chess symbol unicode block and has a license which fits your purpose. Most fonts are in TrueType format which is already vector-based and can be converted to SVG with [Apache SVG Font Converter](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/font-converter.html). This would mean you wouldn't even need to redraw them manually.

Comment: Have you seen that my example is actually taken from there? Why are you sending me back my example as an answer?

Comment: @SalvadorDali Do you have a citation in your question? If not, I'm not sure why you expect someone not to post this. +1 to this answer.

Comment: @BroSlow click the link in sasha's answer. Check the image in my question. As you will notice - they are the same. I did not include the direct link to the page, because I wanted the image to be visible from the beginning.

Comment: @SalvadorDali you still could had put an attribution beside your image, like I did now – I hope I found the right source for your second image.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I suggested an edit to the answer which might explain how this answer could help you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure unicode has a range of codes for both white and black game pieces.

Use a font like Arial or Tahoma. In the U2600 Range.

Answer (score 1):

When you are looking for more interesting Chess icons including heterodox pieces, look here for a great list:

http://www.chessvariants.org/index/imagequery.php?type=DTP&numberofcols=2&displayauthor=1&displayinventor=1&usethisheading=Desktop+Publishing+Resources+By+Image

If you are going for the simple, just use Unicode.