# Where I can download images of chess pieces for my chess app?

Tags: pieces

I am developing an Android app and I need chess pieces images for my it. I am concerned about copyright issues as well. I can copy images from other chess apps on GitHub projects, but I am not sure if that is legal. Is there any free source to get images of chess pieces?

Comment: [This](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/6272/21604) might help you.

Comment: @wimi hey, Thanks for that link, very useful!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the licenses of the piece sets that lichess uses: https://github.com/ornicar/lila/blob/master/COPYING.md#exceptions-free

Personally I am using the cburnett piece set for my project.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that link but I am still concerned about the license, for example `cburnett` pieces have  `Apache License 2.0` .https://github.com/LexLuengas/chessnut-pieces/blob/master/LICENSE.txt  it says
`A permissive license whose main conditions require preservation of copyright and license notices..`  does that mean I have to add some kind of license file in my app?

Comment: @beginner yes, you would have to include in your app a copy of the Apache 2.0 license text (i.e., the file LICENSE.txt in that repository) AND also a copy of the copyright notice (which is in file COPYRIGHT.txt). You would also have to state it if you change the piece sets. You can do all this in an "About" screen that can be accessed through the "Settings" button in your app. If you write "about:licensing" on Firefox, you can see an example of such a screen. You can ask questions about licensing on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @wimi thank you so much for your help, but actually I was looking for a free and standard version of pieces, those pieces are a bit too fancy for my app and tey also require adding copyright and license text, anyway thanks for your help:)